# Boot from flash drive then start VirtualBox

Tags: linux, boot, virtualbox, usb-flash-drive

I want to put a very small OS on a flash drive with minimum necessary requirements for running VirtualBox 64 bit machines. Can I make it with Tiny Linux or something similar?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish? Like a persistent live installation? Would you want to boot into the Linux distro? Or have it load in the background and then load the VM automatically? What is the end result you are looking for?

Comment: I want to have more resources available to run my VMs. Because Windows and Ubuntu consumes too much memory I would replace them for a small OS.

Answer (score 0):

You can surely do that with any Ubuntu Distros with persistence enabled.
Use Universal USB Installer For Linux(Windows OS) [Universal USB Installer User Guide](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/). Select the distro of your choice(Ubuntu 10.04) and locate it's ISO file(CD Image), select the USB Drive letter and check **mark** the Persistence Storage and specify persistence storage to 2 GB(preferably). FYI, Persistence Storage is a fixed area that can be used to store your Virtualbox all the files.

Comment: You might want to add a little more information. I can imagine the OP does not know what persistence is for example.

Answer (score 0):

You could install Ubuntu to the USB drive, install VirtualBox to the USB and then boot from the USB to install the Virtual Machine. Once the VM is installed you could then write some sort of start-up script to launch the VM when the USB is inserted and booted from, once it reaches the Ubuntu desktop.

Bear in mind running a OS *and* a Virtual Machine from a USB drive will not be that fast. Also depending on the VM hard disk you would need a fairly sizeable USB stick as well.